# PHP prevent user from pasting invalid character

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have used this plugin http://itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/ so the user types only alphanumeric characters.

But I have found that the user can paste an invalid character and submit it .
My question how to prevent him from pasting invalid character or preventing submit or check for invalid character by PHP (server-side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" class="alphanumbersOnly" value="" />

jQuery('.alphanumbersOnly').keyup(function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'');
});
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jcP7m/2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `preg_match`?

```
if(!preg_match("/^[0-9A-Za-z]+$/", $form_input)) { 
    echo "Only alphanumeric characters are allowed."; 
}
```

This checks if the input is one or more alphanumeric characters. If spaces are also allowed, add a space to the range: `"/^[0-9A-Za-z ]+$/"`

Comment: I don't want ' to be entered, how to do that ? I have tried your solution but it doesn't work

Comment: My solution relies on PHP to check the input after it is submitted. The range doesn't contain ' so you don't need to do anything extra.